# Joomla Module: How to read ini language strings from XML module file?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

mod_modulo.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="module" version="1.5.0">
    <name>**EXTNAME**</name> 
    <description>**EXTDESCR**</description>
    <files>
    .
    .
    .
    </files> 
    <languages>
        <language tag="en-US">languages/en-US.mod_modulo.ini</language>
        <language tag="es-ES">languages/es-ES.mod_modulo.ini</language>
    </languages>
</install>
```

es-ES.mod_modulo.xml:

```
EXTNAME=Mi modulo
EXTDESCR=Descripcion de mi modulo va aqui
```

I am using Joomla!1.5 to develop modules because I think that newer versions of Joomla are compatible with older modules. Anyway, the question is: How can I set the values of *name* and *description* in mod_module.xml to the strings found in the corresponding language file ?

Comment: Dont use a Joomla 1.5 standards to develop. Joomla 1.5 is old, unsupported and people should be moving on from it and there will also be changes with the language files

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5's component installation manifest definition includes a section for administrator interface language files:

```xml
...
<administration>
    <languages folder="administrator/language/">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_my.ini</language>
        <language tag="es-ES">es-ES/es-ES.com_my.ini</language>
    </languages>
</administration>
...
```

However, this specification does not work for modules in that version.

The Document type definition used by J1.5's manifest files is no longer served.

Thant's why I am not sure whether the failure to copy the language files to the admin section's folder is a bug or is done by design. Their removal during the uninstallation process indicated that it is indeed a bug.

Joomla! v1.5 module installation is performed by `libraries/joomla/installer/adapters/module/php`.

This file is not accessing this node during the installation, but is deleting it during uninstall it deletes it:

```php
$this->parent->removeFiles($root->getElementByPath('administration/languages'), 1);
```

**What can you do?**

Legacy packages support in 2.5 and 3.x requires compromises. I would personally advise against it, as it cripples your design.

Therefoe, you can either write a Joomla! 2.5+ module, or you can try to hack your way around this, which would not be pretty. Modules don't event have installation scripts, so you cannot even copy the language files during the module installation process.

The first thing that comes to mind is copying the language files to the administrator folder the first time the controller is invoked.

All this should, hopefully, convince you (and anyone reading this post) to switch to the current Joomla! version.

Comment: So, in other words, J1.5 XML manifest files are not internationalizable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your xml file

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-US">languages/en-US.mod_modulo.ini</language>
    <language tag="es-ES">languages/es-ES.mod_modulo.ini</language>
</languages>
```

in your mod_modulo.ini file

```
EXTNAME="Mi modulo"
EXTDESCR="Descripcion de mi modulo va aqui"
```

in your default.php file have.

```
echo "Name :".JText::_('EXTNAME');
echo "Description:".JText::_('EXTDESCR');
```

Hope its help you..

Comment: Your code retrieves strings when called from PHP not the manifest XML